# NSIS Scripting, difference between CallInstDLL and Plugin DLL

Tags: nsis

The title has pretty much covered my question.

`CallInstDLL` is straigh forward and documented [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/CallInstDLL).

`CallInstDLL $INSTDIR\somedll.dll somefunction`

Question is how is it different from a plugin (also called extension DLL). Extension DLLs are invoked as below

`MyExtDll::MyFunction arg1 arg2 ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in the generated code, Dll::Export is just a syntax shortcut.

`MyExtDll::MyFunction arg1 arg2` is expanded to something like this:

```
InitPluginsDir
File "/oname=$pluginsdir\MyExtDll.dll" "${NSISDIR}\Plugins\MyExtDll.dll"
Push arg2
Push arg1
CallInstDll "$pluginsdir\MyExtDll.dll" MyFunction
```

Comment: `CallInstDll` uses System.dll internally? I want to avoid System.dll being loaded process space.

Comment: No, CallInstDll is basically just LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress.